# OpenShift with Comodo SSL

Tags: ssl, openshift

I am trying to upload the SSL certificates for my OpenShift gear's alias.  I used the instructions here: http://cloudhostingsource.com/setup-ssl-certificate-openshift/

I am stuck however at the uploading part - I have already genereated the CSR, activated the certificate.  Every time I try to upload the files it takes me back to the same page without so much as a notification.

Comodo SSL sent me 4 files:

1. AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
2. COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
3. COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
4. myApp.crt

How do I upload these?  There are three fields to upload for Openshift... Which do I load into SSL Certificate?  Certificate chain?  I have my private key and I know the keypass.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to post an update for this for users who run into this issue in the future...  I'm not sure if it was because I had added a public SSH key via the RHC setup but nothing I did (no permutations of copy paste chaining, switching files around) would work via the file uploader.

In the end, before deciding to call Red Hat and QQ, I used the command line console to add the SSL files...

Here is the command I used:

rhc alias update-cert php www.myapp.com --certificate myApp.crt --private-key  myApp.key --passphrase mypass

This link includes more info:  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/Using_Custom_SSL_Certificates1.html

TLDR:  You don't need to combine any of the Comodo files, just use your file #4, your privatekey, and your passphrase (if you have one)

Answer (score 1):

Thats right!

First combine public with bundle:

```
cat dom_com.crt dom_com.ca-bundle >> dom_com.ALL.bundle
```

and upload both:

```
rhc alias update-cert app dom_com \
    --certificate dom_com.ALL.bundle \
    --private-key dom_com.key
```

And then you will obtain an **A** at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine 1,2, and 3 into one chain certificate (in the correct order) and upload them in the chain certificate field, the key goes in the key field, and the myApp.crt goes in the certificate field.

Comment: This isn't working... I combined the first three into a file - should they be in that order?  Is there a specific extension it needs to be?  When I press save (after following your instructions) it does the same thing as usual and just ignores the upload and refreshes the page.

Comment: You would have to ask the place you got your certificate from what order they go in.  They should be the .crt extension for the certificates, and .key for the private key.  If you have a password on your key, make sure you enter it there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and after some back and forth emails with the Certificate issuer, what helped me was to combine my site certificate with the Certificate chain into one file, and uploading it into the "SSL Certificate" field in OpenShift. I left the "SSL Certificate Chain" field blank, but of course I uploaded my public key in the "Certificate Private Key" field.